# How can i move text in a text file down one line, append to the top, and then remove the bottom line in PHP?

Tags: php

The text file i need to edit would look something like this, for reference:

```
Line 1: Hello!
Line 2: Ah i see.
Line 3: Yes i like chocolate too.
Line 4: Do you like chocolate?
```

The way that I'd like it to function:

1. User enters text on website
2. Text is send over to the server and received by a PHP file
3. (This bit i don't know how to do) The PHP file moves all text in the text file down by one line, so line 1 which says "Hello!" will now be on Line 2, and then clears Line 5, so Line 4 would move to line 5 and then be cleared.

It would probably be nice to also know how to do the reverse of this, so add text the bottom, shift all previous text up one line, and clear the top line. Thanks if anyone can help me!

Comment: Look at `file()` and `array_unshift` and `array_pop`.

Comment: There are several parts to your project, which have you solved? What exactly are your problems with the others?

Answer (score 0):

@AbraCadaver is putting you on the right track.

```
<?php

function shiftFileDown(string $path): array {
    $contentArray = file($path);
    array_unshift($contentArray, "\n"); // Or null, '', whatever
    array_pop($contentArray);

    return $contentArray;
}

function shiftFileUp(string $path): array {
    $contentArray = file($path);
    array_shift($contentArray);
    $contentArray[] = "\n"; // Or null, '', whatever

    return $contentArray;
}
```